# como puedo ordenar los siguientes datos usando regex en python?

Tags: python

Tengo un fichero que tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
Nombre1 = Funcion(New func("")) 'comentarios
Nombre2 = Funcion(New func("")) 'comentarios
Nombre3 = Funcion(New func("")) 'comentarios
```

Necesito que donde haya doble quote o doble comillas, se ponga asi `\"\"`
A parte necesito quitar todos los comentarios y que el fichero resultado sea tal que asi:

```
Nombre1 = Funcion(Texto Valor(\"\")):Nombre2 = Funcion(New func(\"\")):Nombre3 = Funcion(New func(\"\"))
```

Todas mis variables iran en una sola linea y eliminare todos los comentarios; ademas de saltos de linea, el resultado sera tal como mencione antes.
Es posible hacer esto usando regex en python para no tener que hacerlo a mano?

Comment: El carácter `'` sólo puede aparecer cuando se trata de un comentario, o puede ser usado también como delimitador de cadena, es decir, puede aparecer `'blah'`? ¿O puede aparecer también dentro de otra cadena delimitada con `"`, como por ejemplo: `"O'Brian"`?

Answer (score 1):

No hacer falta usar *expresiones regulares*.

Para cambiar las *comillas* basta un simple `.replace('""', '\"\"')`; para quitar los comentarios, con un `.split("'")[0]`; y para juntar todo `":".join()`

```
def sin_comentarios(s):
    return s.split("'")[0]

with open("fichero.txt") as f:
    lines = (sin_comentarios(l[:-1]) for l in f.readlines())
    res = ":".join(linea.replace('""', '\"\"') for linea in lines)
```

<strike>**Nota**: código sin probar</strike>

Comment: me devuelve este error: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Lo raro es que te devuelva un error. He corregido el código y he comprobado que funciona en python3.

Comment: me hace un salto de espacio entre linea y linea  Funcion(New func("")) (espacio):Nombre2 = Funcion(New func("")) no habria alguna forma de evitarlo?

Comment: Sí, con `.strip()`

Comment: osea que tendria que hacer un strip al final de la linea?